# Creating object array to pass in Constructor

Tags: java

Being a newbie to Java am finding it a bit difficult to come up with a neat code for my purpose.

The problem is,

```
class ElementID {

  String name = "";
  String value = "";

  public ElementID (String name, String value) {
   this.name = name;
   this.value = value;
  }
}

class HeaderID {

  String ID = "";
  Date cal;
  ElementID[] elementID;

  public HeaderID (String ID, Calender cal, ElementID[] elemID) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.cal = cal;
    this.elementID = elemID;
   }
}
```

Now in another class inside a function i need to instantiate the HeaderID class.

And this is what i did so far and it doesn't work. The problem am facing is with regard to creating a single array of ElementID.

```
ElementID[] e = new ElementID[1];
e[0] = new ElementID("NAME", "VALUE");

// Error at this line
HeaderID ht = new HeaderID("ID", new Date(), e);
```

Comment: `Date` vs `Calendar`? It would help if you read and posted the error.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot cast direct from `Date` to `Calendar`:

You declared:

```
public HeaderID (String ID, Calender cal, ElementID[] elemID) {
```

and you try to call:

```
HeaderID ht = new HeaderID("ID", new Date(), e); //Error at this line
//                               ^ this is expecting a Calendar Instance
```

**OPTION A:** You can change you declaration

```
public HeaderID (String ID, Date date, ElementID[] elemID) {
```

If you do this use your actual call:

```
HeaderID ht = new HeaderID("ID", new Date(), e);
```

**OPTION B**: change what you send to your actual declaration:

```
// create new calendar instance
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

// put desired Date
cal.setTime(new Date());

// make call with correct variable types
HeaderID ht = new HeaderID("ID", cal, e);
```

Comment: The problem is not with Calendar or Date. Please see updated question. The issue am getting is with regard to ElementID

Comment: There is no problem with `ElementID[] e = new ElementID[1];
e[0] = new ElementID("NAME", "VALUE");` this part is correct... the problem is when you try to put a Date in a Calendar...

Comment: @donguy76 the problem **is** `Calendar` vs `Date`. Also, I recommend you using `Date` rather than `Calendar` field, or even better, use the new time api from Java 8.

Comment: @donguy76 if you don't think the answers that have been provided are correct, please post the exact error you are getting.